# How to install samba-tool on Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, samba, amazon-linux

I am using Amazon Linux on AWS and wish to install the CLI application of samba-tool. On Linux distributions including Ubuntu, this is included by default with installing samba, but does not appear to be available after running `yum install samba`. It also does not exist in the location `/usr/local/samba/bin/samba-tool` referenced in the documentation.

How do I install samba-tool on Amazon Linux?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to compile Samba from source at this time to access the samba-tool binary, the Centos8 and Fedora build specs are pretty similar to what you need on Amazon Linux 2.